# how to display date based on locale in p:chart line date axis

Tags: primefaces, internationalization, jqplot

I am working with primefaces line chart. my primefaces version is 6.2 charts y axis is an integer and x is date,
i am dispalying date in dd mmm format in chart, i want to display date in the chart in chinese when i change the locale.

i tried to change the date using date formatter in java based on locale, it will return date in chinese,
once i set these to min and max date chart is not rendering , again if i change the locale to english it works.

xhtml

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{ManagerClass.lineChart}"
style="height:133px;" />
```

java code

```
lineChart.addSeries(lineSeries);
    lineChart.setSeriesColors("E53935");
    Axis yAxis = lineChart.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.setMax(maxLimit);
    yAxis.setTickFormat("%d");
    DateAxis axis = new DateAxis();
    axis.setTickAngle(-50);
    axis.setMin(minDate);
    axis.setMax(maxDate);
    axis.setTickInterval("Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY");
    lineSeries.setLabel("No. of users");
    lineChart.setLegendPosition("e");
    axis.setTickFormat("%d %b");
```

do i have to add any js file for primefaces to display chinese dates.

Comment: so it works in a bar chart?

Comment: same result in bar chart as well. If a use any locale which are similar to english, it works. as soon as i set locale to chinese chart doesn't render. my code will print date in these format for chinese in cosole.  Locale.setDefault(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
 return sdf.format(date);